# Business rule: Add other field value to date?

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, powerapps-modeldriven

I'm trying to programmatically set the Due Date field of a custom activity. I want take the value of another date-time field that the users enters and add the value from an integer field. But it seems that I can only select a static value to add using the business rules as shown here:

[image: Field Value]

Is there a way to do it using business rules? Or do I have to use a Javascript instead?

Comment: Sorry but no I haven't! I'll find a way :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use calculated field for these scenarios, but it is not a physical field to store. If you have to store the value, then Javascript or plugin or WF is better.

Business rules are limited in these situations.

Comment: You can always use a business rule to set a date field to the value of a calculated date field too, if you want to get there without code.

Answer (score 0):

This should be quite easy using PowerApps expression language; no need for PowerApps "Rules" (which are [slated to be deprecated](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/canvas-rules-feature-deprecation/)).

**To your app:**

1. Add a DatePicker control
2. Add a TextBox control
3. Add a Label control

**Set the Label control's `Text` property to:**

```
DateAdd(
    DatePicker.Selected.Value, 
    Value(TextBox.Text), 
    Days
)
```

**Bingo!**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input! I realize that I didn't express in the text but only with my tags that I'm dealing with a model-driven app

Comment: Hm. Bummer. You can see how easy this is with Canvas app.